# Getting an error while trying to upgrade from oracle 11.2.0.3 to oracle-12.1.0.2-32

Tags: java, oracle

We are trying to move our database from oracle 11.2.0.3 to oracle-12.1.0.2-32 . While we are trying to establish the connection we are getting the below error. Could you please let us know if we are missing any libraries or something else? Any sort of guidance on this would help us.

Error connecting to database [java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Fetch error message failed!]

Tried to just change the class path to point to oracle 12c package

Whereever we are doing the dbmanager.getconenction we are getting the error like 
Error connecting to database [java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Fetch error message failed!]

We need the database conenction to be establisjed so that we can bring up the application .

Comment: Have you confirmed that your ORACLE_HOME environment variable is set to the proper location for the upgraded database? Are you using the JDBC OCI Driver? If yes, then the OCI library version and JDBC Driver version must match.  If it's feasible, using the JDBC thin driver instead of JDBC OCI may resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi yes the oracle home variable is set correctly . We were using OCI driver. Now i am trying to change it to thin and see if it makes any difference. Previously we were using ORAQCLE 10 with classes12.zip. I am now trying to move to Oracle 12 and i have replacede the classes12.zip with the ojdbc6.jar .